# Vertically centering content with fullpage.js

Tags: fullpage.js

According to the *fullpages.js* documentation, it should be possible to vertically center the contents of `.section`s with the parameter `verticallyCentered` (which defaults to `true`).

However, I can't get this feature to work with the following HTML structure:

```
<div id="content">
    <div class="section container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-12">
                <h1 class="title">Title</h1>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The content of the `.col-xs-12` div (i.e. the heading) remains at the top of the window.

I am using Bootstrap for scaffolding (if that is of any relevance). Also, the basic functionality of fullpage.js (i.e. the single-page scrolling) is working without any problems.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are probably using some absolute positioned element and that's the reason why fullpage.js can not deal with it.

You can easily see [in the examples](http://alvarotrigo.com/fullPage/) that fullpage.js centers the content correctly when using `verticalCentered:true`, which is the default value.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue.
I fixed it by styling the default class, added by fullpage.js:

```
.fp-tableCell {
 display: flex;
 align-items: center;
 justify-content: center;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Since I couldn't get the vertical centering functionality to work, I ended up disabling it by setting `verticalCentered` to `false`. As a replacement I am now using [jQuery-Flex-Vertical-Center](https://github.com/PaulSpr/jQuery-Flex-Vertical-Center) which works out of the box.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry to resurrect this question but the problem is that you didn't include the css file of FullPage.js